# Google AppMaker: Failed to load models for google cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

Within the Google AppMaker, I am trying to connect to an external data source, in this case an existing Google Cloud SQL.

As prompted I supply the projectName:regionName:instanceName/databaseName and the username and password, but that's as far as I get, as this error's with;

"Import external Model:
Failed to load models for google Cloud SQL"

The cloud SQL database is MySQL 5.7

Any tips or pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that was the same error message I was getting for no apparent reason.

I fixed it updating the user and pass.
Enter your Cloud SQL username and password again.

App Settings -> Google Cloud SQL -> SQL preview credentials -> Update

You may have to do it every time it fails.

This kept happening to me for the first few days using Cloud SQL.

Comment: Thanks for pointer. It seems that a combination of doing the above and re-adding The account (appmaker-maestro@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) as an editor to the project, worked.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by a combination of;

- Entering the Cloud SQL username and password again (App Settings -> Google Cloud SQL -> SQL preview credentials -> Update).
- Ensuring that the account (appmaker-maestro@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) is listed correctly as an editor to the project ( [IAM & Admin Projects Page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project)).

It's now loaded my model !